# Template: How do override the default file bootstrap sass?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

It is possible to override the default file bootstrap without changing file in bower_components ?

Or is better changing in original file?

Ex: I create new file `_alerts.scss` in app:

```
My_project
|
|__ bower_components
|    |__ bootstrap-sass-official
|        |__ assets
|            |__ stylesheets
|                |__ boostrap
|                    |__ _alerts.scss
|
|__ app
|    |__ template (create)
|        |__ bootstrap-sass-official (create)
|            |__ assets (create)
|                |__ stylesheets (create)
|                    |__ boostrap (create)
|                        |__ _alerts.scss (new file)
|__ node_module
|__ test
|__ bower.json
|__ Gruntfile.js
|__ package.json
```

Grunt override _alerts.scss in folder `app` for original file in bower_components.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to change files inside the `bower_components` folder. To solve your problem, you need to include every file of Bootstrap directly in your SASS file.

See this little paragraph in the Bootstrap-sass repo : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#configuration. You then just have to comment the import of `bootstrap/alerts` and import yours instead !